# In India, does inheritance income need to be declared while filing returns?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, gift-tax, inheritance

In India, does inheritance income need to be declared while filing returns? What if the said income is received as a cheque from the nominee? For example, consider that a parent with three children nominated the eldest on a fixed deposit of 24 lacs. After receiving funds from the bank, the nominee issues a cheque of 8 lacs to each of her two siblings. I understand that under Indian law, none of them are liable to pay any tax on this account. But do they have to declare the income? If so, is there a particular form for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In India, does inheritance income need to be declared while filing returns?

No

> I understand that under Indian law, none of them are liable to pay any tax on this account.

Yes there is no tax for any of them.

> But do they have to declare the income? If so, is there a particular form for this?

No. But its advisable to keep a record of the said transaction and the purpose. i.e. it was a Gift from parent and gifted to 2 other siblings. This will make it easy if there is a scrutiny from the tax department.